# Inserting wider banner than div

Tags: css

Our designer created a new banner for a site that's (intentionally) wider than the previous one. Is there some CSS magic that lets me insert it (centered) in place of the old one, without going into cropping and creating new divs on both side?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative margins:

```
.wide-banner {
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

You may need to use negative right-margins too, depending on the other content in your page.

Comment: God, it was so simple. Thank you!